# JQuery data() call

Tags: jquery

Could anyone explain the difference between this:

Update 1- reverting phrases

```
container.data("state", { test: 1 }); // works
```

and this:

```
 container.data["state"] = { test: 1 }; // doesn't work
```

I found that the first construction works, while the last one doesn't. The call populates container with the initial data, i.e. "state" is blank when it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a function, not an array. You're trying to access an index of a function in the second snippet, which doesn't work.

See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

For example, open up your Development Console in your browser, and type something like this:

```
$("a:eq(0)").data
```

I get a long function definition, not an array:

```
function (a,c){var d,e,g,h=null;if(typeof a=="undefined"){if(this.length){h=f.data(this[0]);if(this[0].nodeType===1&&!f._data(this[0],"parsedAt.... // continued
```

Comment: makes sense. does data support referencing  i.e. the instance of data retrieved by var data = $("a").data("b"); b.test = "c"; can I assume that after calling it my $("a").data("b").test will be set to "c"?

Comment: Good question. Let me look into it.

Comment: I think the answer is no. `data` stores copies (probably shallow copies) of whatever you pass: http://jsfiddle.net/NSADm/